# How to access SysListView32 elements in QTP?

Tags: qtp, syslistview32

We are having a table of elements in SysListView32. Actually they are a table arranged under 5 columns. How to access 3rd column in the table in SysListView32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out - we must use the sReport method to access the particulat column element
Eg:

```
sReport = sReport &  .GetSubItem("123", 2) & vbCr
```

wherein "123" is the S.No. and it will access the 3rd column with S.No. = "123"
sReport should be accessed by With Objectname

Answer (score 0):

sReport is not required to get the data. That is being used for only reporting purposes.
Instead you can also try the below.

```
Var = Window().WinlistView().GetSubItem (Row, Col)
Where row => you can get by using the GetItem in a loop
and Col => you can get by using GetColumnHeader
```

For more details go to QTP help and search for GetSubItem and click on the example Implementation.